# Local field 'created_at' in class 'BandRating' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'Rating'

Tags: django

I've recently tried to create two separate models inheriting from `Rating` but upon migration I get the error mentioned in the title. I assume this is due to rogue migrations as it seems that there should be no clashes in my code? I initially had `Rating` which had two optional fields, `Venue` or `Band` but I feel this is better structure.

For future reference, what would be the ideal way to do this without running into this kind of issue?

```
class Rating(models.Model, Activity):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_author(self):
        if self.author is None:
            return "Anonymous"
        else:
            return self.author

    @property
    def activity_actor_attr(self):
        return self.author


class BandRating(Rating):
    band = models.ForeignKey(Band)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.band) + " rating"


class VenueRating(Rating):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.venue) + " rating"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to "hide" the `Rating.created_at` field which is declared in the `Activity` model from which you inherit - that's not possible when inheriting from a non-abstract model.

More info here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted

Comment: My fault for not checking the `Activity` model. Cheers